# Using jQuery, keep a form's submit button disabled until all of the required textbox, radio, checkbox elements have a value (or are checked)

Tags: jquery, forms

Hello Kind People of StackExchange,

I have encountered a stumbling block over some code I'm working with and I have included a collapsed example of the HTML I am working with in the hope that you might be able to kindly help me piece together the remaining jQuery portion.

The objective here is to keep the submit button disabled until ANY element with a class of .Required has some sort of value or other attribute such as "checked". So the solution needs to cover select, radio, checkbox, textbox and textarea elements (those elements will have the Required class).

```
<script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="someaction/action" method="post" class="DisableSubmit">

    <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="100" autofocus="true" placeholder="Title..." value="" style="width: 90%;" />

    <textarea name="text" rows="3" style="width: 90%;"></textarea>

    <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="100" placeholder="Location..." value="" class="Required" style="width: 90%;" />
    <p class="explain">Required</p>

    <label for="i_agree">
        <span class="label">I agree to the terms and conditions:</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="i_agree" class="Required" />
    </label>
    <p class="explain">Required</p>

    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I know how to handle this if all the fields are the same type, but struggling with this current scenario. Any advice as ever is gratefully received.

Many thanks

Comment: Why do validation from scratch?  http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Thank you. But on this occasion that plugin is a little bit overkill for the requirements. Thanks again for the comment, though :)

Comment: it's not a solution but you can also upgrade your code with [required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use more HTML5-like style

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var required = $('[required]');
    // bind change for all you just click, and keyup for all textfields
    required.bind('change keyup', function() {
        var flag = 0;
        // check every el in collection
        required.each(function() {
            if ($(this).not(':checkbox, :radio').val() || $(this).filter(':checked').val()) flag++;
        });
        // if number of nonempty (nonchecked) fields == nubmer of required fields minus one excess radio input
        if (flag==required.length-1) $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled',false);
        else $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

### [working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EvRb5/)

**EDIT** As my wife noticed (*thank you, I love you, darling*) this example is not working with checkboxes and radio buttons correctly, because even unchecked, they always return their positive value.

So I updated my code and demo and I want to explain the difference. First of all, I changed condition, now it looks like `if ($(this).not(':checkbox, :radio').val() || $(this).filter(':checked').val())` - in the 1st part we delete all checkboxes and radio buttons from collection, and in the 2nd we check value of all "checked" inputs (that means all checked inputs, deleted in 1st part).

The next untidy step is to use a number, like `required.length-1` to reduce number of all unnecessary radio fields manually

I'm still trying to find better solution, but now you can check this **[new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EvRb5/2/)**

Comment: `$('[required]')` is this valid ?..sorry correct me if im wrong

Comment: @ubercooluk yes, it is the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), which will select all elements with attribute `required`

Comment: it's double protection both with [required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute and jQuery

Comment: Fantastic.1) I had no idea about the required attribute. I was at the end of my tether yesterday and at one point I'd have happily said a big "so what" to it requiring a compatible browser. 2) What a brilliant answer. Now we have a solution that should work in most browsers. I have tested it out and it works great. I made a couple of changes, purely to have the button disabled by default on page load. Everything else is absolutely spot on. Thank you to you and your wife :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552672/count-the-current-number-of-inputs-with-a-specific-property-after-a-function-has Have come across a few issues...

Comment: @PHPNewbGallery ok, give me some minutes

Answer (score 1):

this should do it ;)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Required").on('input', function() {
        reqAll();
    });
    $(".Required").on('change', function() {
        reqAll();
    });
    var reqAll = function () {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('Required');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            switch(elements[i].type) {
                case "radio":
                    if( elements[i].checked == false) {
                        $('.button').attr('disabled', true);
                        return;  // bail if unselected
                    }
                    break;
                case "select-one":
                    if( elements[i].selectedIndex == 0) {
                        $('.button').attr('disabled', true);
                        return;     // bail if unselected
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if( elements[i].value == "" ) {
                        $('.button').attr('disabled', true);
                        return;     // bail if empty
                    }
            }
        }
        $('.button').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: it's strange `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('Required');` why not use `$('.Required')` again?