# Count the current number of inputs with a specific property after a function has run which has changed these properties

Tags: jquery, forms, prop

Related to this question: [Using jQuery, keep a form's submit button disabled until all of the required textbox, radio, checkbox elements have a value (or are checked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515599/using-jquery-keep-a-forms-submit-button-disabled-until-all-of-the-required-tex)

I was very kindly helped to put together this function

```
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');

    var required = $('[required]');

    required.bind('change keyup', function()
    {
        var flag = 0;
        required.each(function()
        {   
            if ($(this).not(':checkbox, :radio').val() || $(this).filter(':checked').val())
            {
                flag++;
            }
        });

        if (flag == required.length)
        {
            $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
        }
        else
        {
            $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
        }
    });
```

What's happening here is that the submit button of a form is staying disabled until all fields with the "required" property have some sort of value (or have been checked, etc.).

Part of a bigger picture, another jQuery function (which works fine) is hiding some of these fields depending on the value of a select box.

Effectively, when those fields are hidden, the required property should be removed. With the required property being removed, I would expect the above function to count (required.length) only the remaining required fields, but in fact, it counts all of them -- even those ones that no longer have the required property.

Any ideas on a way around this?

Comment: Instead of storing the selected elements in a variable (`required`), you could re-select them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the same set of elements over and over again.  You need to re-select the ones that you need during each check.

Change

```
required.each(function()
```

To

```
$([required]).each(function()
```

You are selecting all the element and then looping through them regardless of the properties that they now have.  You want to have jQuery re-select the elements that now have the `required` property so that you get an updated list.  This should then perform as you expect.

Comment: I feel rather silly that I missed this... Oh well, at least I won't make the same mistake again!! Thank you, this basically does what I need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

you have not only remove `required` atribute, but also 1. `.unbind('change keyup')` for this element 2. remove it from collection with `required = required.not('[required]');`

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/Xtwnp/) gives basic idea: before you click button both required inputs alert their number, after you click it, total length is reduced and second input stops to alert

don't forget to bind `change keyup` if you make it required again

Comment: Thank you again for your help, vladkras. @Schleis came up with the best answer on this occasion. But I really appreciate you providing this solution and being kind enough to offer your time to help me (again). Thank you.

Comment: @PHPNewbGallery it's very strange because when you delete `requried` attr - it doesn't meen you `unbind` `event` from element, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/Xtwnp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
|| $(this).css('display') === 'none')
```

to the if around flag++.